# line 15: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Filter'

Tags: geoserver, layers, sld, geoserver-rest-api

I have defined the following SLD rule for my layer. It says that if the property `Weekday` is greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 3, then the color of a polygon must be `#680000`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>green</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Name>Adjustable</Name>
      <Title>Triangle</Title>
      <Abstract>Direction and volume</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Volume control</Title>
          <Abstract>Volume control</Abstract>
          <Filter>
            <And>
              <PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>Weekday</PropertyName>
                <Literal>1</Literal>
              </PropertyIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
              <PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
                <PropertyName>Weekday</PropertyName>
                <Literal>3</Literal>
              </PropertyIsLessThanOrEqualTo>
            </And>
          </Filter>
          <PolygonSymbolizer>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#680000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke/>
          </PolygonSymbolizer>
        </Rule>      
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

When I validate this rule in Geoserver 2.11, I get the following error:

> line 15: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting
>   with element 'Filter'. One of
>   '{"http://www.opengis.net/sld":LegendGraphic,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/ogc":Filter,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/sld":ElseFilter,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MinScaleDenominator,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/sld":MaxScaleDenominator,
>   "http://www.opengis.net/sld":Symbolizer}' is expected.

Line 15 is `<Filter>`. I checked [the documentation of SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/rules.html#sld-reference-rules) and it looks like I defined all mandatory fields. Why do I get this error message and how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct namespace for the filter element as the error message says.

Filter is in OGC name space so you need to use ogc: as a prefix and make sure you have declared it.